# Problems cloning repo from git hub

Tags: git

Okay so I've been struggling with this for hours. I get this message.

```
~$ git clone git@github.com:bjm3590/odin-recipes.git
Cloning into 'odin-recipes'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.114.3)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU.

This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? 
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have already created an SSH key on github. but when i try to pull the repo from there using the command line. this is what I get. any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SSH is in difference to HTPS/TLS a system that does not make use of certificate authorities to verify the authenticity of a certain server.

SSH uses the system "trust on first use" that means every time you connect to an SSH server the first time the ssh client will show you the server key hash and ask you if trust the key.

For GitHub the possible [public server key hashes are documented](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints) so you can simply compare the key with the one from the website and if it matches accept the key.

Even without having such a source of the trusted keys the risk would be very low in your case as you use an ssh key for authentications which means nobody can steal you the key by redirecting you to a different ssh server (man-in-the-middle attack) as the SSH client key in only used but never transmitted.